# Where do i add custom PHP code in Wordpress custom template?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, templates

Hy all! From what I read, the best way to add PHP code to a wordpress page would be via a custom template. So i took the **page.php** from the theme and customised it with html code without any problems. The problem is with the PHP code. No matter where I add it, it doesn't work.

**My question is where do I add the custom PHP code for the form validation?**

The page looks like this:

```
/*
Template Name: example
*/

<?php
get_header();
if ($tempera_frontpage=="Enable" && is_front_page()): get_template_part( 'frontpage' );
else :
?>

<section id="container" class="<?php echo tempera_get_layout_class(); ?>">
<div id="content" role="main">
<?php cryout_before_content_hook(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content/content', 'page'); ?>

I added the HTML code here:  

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> " >
.....
</form>

<?php
endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/form-validation-with-php/), you will add it before the HTML, near the top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well basically it's PHP and should work, if you want to validate the form in the same template file, use an empty action attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="">
.....
</form>
```

And make sure not to use an WordPress reserved word on your form element name attribute, for example `name`.

At the top of the file you can verify and validate all the request being sent by the form as any other PHP file.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  //validate or do something here
}
get_header();
if ($tempera_frontpage=="Enable" && is_front_page()): get_template_part( 'frontpage' );
else :
?>
```

Hope this solution help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was an easy solution and it works. One more question, is there any way to incorporate the original action code? From what i read it's preety important for the form validation

Comment: You can still add the current url to the action, for example: `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; ?>">` or look for a way to use the FULL url here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you should be modifying the content-page.php template.  Note the page template calls it with:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content/content', 'page'); ?>
```

Within the content template you should see something like

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

If you add the form html on the next line, it will be within the same div, something like

```
<div class="entry-content>
</div>
```

This way the new content will fall within the same container as other content and be styled as such.